# Issue with Regexp with mySQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build a search query which searches for a word in a string and finds matches based on the following criteria:

- The word is surrounded by a combination of either a space, period or comma
- The word is at the start of the string and ends with a space, period or comma
- The word is at the end of the string and is followed by a space, period or comma
- It's a full match, i.e. the entire string is just the word

For example, if the word is 'php' the following strings would be matches:

- php
- mysql, php, javascript
- php.mysql
- javascript php

But for instance it wouldn't match:

- php5

I've tried the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE skillset REGEXP '^|[., ]php[., ]|$'
```

However that doesn't work, it returns every record as a match which is wrong.

Without the ^| and |$ in there, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE skillset REGEXP '[., ]php[., ]'
```

It successfully finds matches where 'php' is somewhere in the string except the start and end of the string. So the problem must be with the ^| and |$ part of the regexp.

How can I add those conditions in to make it work as required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `'\bphp\b'`, `\b` is a word boundary and might just be exactly what you need because it looks for the whole word php.

For MySQL, word boundaries are represented with [[:<:]] and [[:>:]] instead of \b, so use the query '[[:<:]]php[[:>:]]'. More info on word boundaries [here.](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE skillset REGEXP '\bphp\b' returns 0 results but should be several hundred.

Comment: @dlofrodloh hmm, looks like regex for mysql is slightly different. Try '[[:<:]]php[[:>:]]'?

Comment: @Shirley please edit your answer with the fix. Don't leave the solution in the comment please

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can play around a bit with regex101.com

Something I found that works for you but doesn't exactly follow your rules is:

```
/(?=[" ".,]?php[" ".,]?)(?=php[\W])/
```

This uses the lookahead operator, ?=, to do AND
The first portion of the regex is

`[" ".,]?php[" ".,]?`

This will match anything that has a space, period, or comma before or after the php, but at most only one.

The section portion of the regex is

```
php[\W]
```

This will match anything that is php, followed by a non-character. In other words, it will NOT match php followed by a character, digit, or underscore.

It's not the perfect answer for your set of rules, but it does work with your sample data set. Play around on regex101.com and try to make a perfect one.